# class object printing instaed of content

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, class, pickle

i am trying to build a simple database of students (names and ages).
when i tries to delete an excisting student and print the data base it prints me
`<class '__main__.data_base'>`, but if i tries to delete an non excisting student it prints the data base well.

```
import pickle
class data_base:
    data={}
    class __metaclass__(type):
        def __iter__(self):
            for attr in dir(data_base):
                if not attr.startswith("__"):
                    yield attr

    def __init__(self):
        self.write("")

    def write(self,my_data):
        pickle.dump( my_data, open( "database.p", "wb" ) )

    def read(self):
        return pickle.load( open( "database.p", "rb" ) )
    def delete_student(self):
        #delete key and value
        to_delete=raw_input("who do you want to delete? ")
        my_data=self.read()
        if to_delete in my_data.__iter__():
            my_data.pop(to_delete)
            self.write(data_base)
        else:
            print "no such student"

    def clear_data_base(self):
        #delete data baase
        self.write("")

def main():
    first_data={"ben":10,"dan":6}
    my_data_base=data_base()
    my_data_base.clear_data_base()
    my_data_base.write(first_data)
    print my_data_base.read()
    my_data_base.delete_student()
    print my_data_base.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
self.write(data_base)
```

You've pickled the class object not the instance you read into `my_data`. Change your method to

```
def delete_student(self):
    #delete key and value
    to_delete=raw_input("who do you want to delete? ")
    my_data=self.read()
    if to_delete in my_data.__iter__():
        my_data.pop(to_delete)
        self.write(my_data)
    else:
        print "no such student"
```